# viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted

Tags: ios, contacts

How do I fix this issue when opening CNContactPicker

```
 viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted
```

Comment: Please look into the text what you are posting. It need to be readable & clearly understanding to readers. Please rewrite your title.

Comment: iam getting black screen and this error when opening cncontact picker please can u suggest any solution.

Comment: Hello, add some code please, give some details to people, We can help easier.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same exact error with the RPScreenRecorder when trying to present the viewController returned with the stopRecordingWithHandler callback.  I'll keep searching.  This is brand new and only on iPhone X and iPad Pros.

Comment: Are you presenting modally? Most code samples do that. If you are trying something else, we'd need to know. (I've been playing with this, and have problems, but I don't see the error you see).